# Difference Between Schema / Database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, schema, database-schema

Is there a difference between a schema and a database in MySQL?  In SQL Server, a database is a higher level container in relation to a schema.

I read that `Create Schema` and `Create Database` do essentially the same thing in MySQL, which leads me to believe that schemas and databases are different words for the same objects.

Comment: Actually I would say `schema` is better than `database`, as MySQL is a kind of database, and it contains several `database`, and sometimes you `use` a `database`, which makes many searches to miss target.

Answer (score 451, accepted):

As defined in the [MySQL Glossary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

> In MySQL, physically, a ***schema*** is synonymous with a ***database***. You can substitute the keyword `SCHEMA` instead of `DATABASE` in MySQL SQL syntax, for example using `CREATE SCHEMA` instead of `CREATE DATABASE`.
>
> Some other database products draw a distinction. For example, in the Oracle Database product, a ***schema*** represents only a part of a database: the tables and other objects owned by a single user.

Comment: I think "some other database products" is really a euphemism for pretty much every other database (perhaps except SQLite, but that's understandable).

Comment: Making schema synonymous with database is interesting -- I had always associated it with user objects..  And a friendly mention of SQLServer which separated the user/schema concept allowing for a boatload of flexibility and some interesting ways to do dynamic queries.

Comment: The annoying thing about defining "schema" as a grouping of database objects is that it overloads the older meaning of the word, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema.

Comment: @mehaase both are the old meaning of the word. Oracle had schemas before even SQL3 (1999), although it treated them as other databases would tread full-blown databases. In fact, Oracle calls "database" what others call a server or server instance - different binaries, different executables, different ports.

Comment: Users new to MySQL should be acutely aware of this, as dropping a schema may do more than expected. That is, IINM,  DROP SCHEMA equates to DROP DATABASE.

Answer (score 96):

Depends on the database server. `MySQL` doesn't care, its basically the same thing.

`Oracle`, `DB2`, and other enterprise level database solutions make a distinction. Usually a **schema is a collection of tables** and a **Database is a collection of schemas.**

Comment: Even Microsoft SQL Server has very similar distinction as `Oracle` and `DB2` for this case.

Comment: In MySQL "database" and "schema" is not basically the same thing; it is exactly the same thing (for example, `create database` and `create schema` are synonyms). In Oracle schema is synonymous with user (perhaps more accurately, schema is a list of all objects created under a user). MSSQL distinguishes all three (and as a result, when accessing a table from a different database, the name must be qualified by both database and schema, e.g. `database1.dbo.table2`)

Comment: In older versions of SQL Server, a schema was effectively a user. Thankfully that's no longer the case.

Answer (score 23):

Refering to [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html),

> CREATE DATABASE creates a database with the given name. To use this
>   statement, you need the CREATE privilege for the database. CREATE
>   SCHEMA is a synonym for CREATE DATABASE as of MySQL 5.0.2.

Answer (score 21):

PostgreSQL supports schemas, which is a subset of a database:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html

> A database contains one or more named schemas, which in turn contain
>   tables. Schemas also contain other kinds of named objects, including
>   data types, functions, and operators. The same object name can be used
>   in different schemas without conflict; for example, both schema1 and
>   myschema can contain tables named mytable. Unlike databases, schemas
>   are not rigidly separated: a user can access objects in any of the
>   schemas in the database they are connected to, if they have privileges
>   to do so.

Schemas are analogous to directories at the operating system level, except that schemas cannot be nested.

In my humble opinion, MySQL is not a reference database. You should never quote MySQL for an explanation. MySQL implements non-standard SQL and sometimes claims features that it does not support. For example, in MySQL, CREATE schema will only create a DATABASE. It is truely misleading users.

This kind of vocabulary is called "MySQLism" by DBAs.

Comment: And then there is "schemata" to add to confusion for beginners :)

Comment: @Zeni what exactly is a schemata in MySQL?  All I could find are references to the information_schema schemata table but no concise definition as to what it actually means

Comment: @Alf47 "schemata" is just the plural form of the word "schema". "schemas" is also acceptable, but not as fancy :)

Answer (score 11):

in MySQL ***schema*** is synonym of ***database***. 
Its quite confusing for beginner people who jump to MySQL and very first day find the word *schema*, so guys nothing to worry as both are same.

When you are starting MySQL for the first time you need to create a database (like any other database system) to work with so you can **CREATE SCHEMA** which is nothing but **CREATE DATABASE**

In some other database system schema represents a part of database or a collection of Tables, and collection of schema is a database.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, people use these terms interchangeably with regard to MySQL.  Though oftentimes you will hear people inappropriately refer to the entire database server as the database.

Answer (score 3):

Simply if you are **thinking or discussing** about **Mysql**. Then take a **simple answer**

> "**SCHEMA & DATABASE are exactly the same thing, just a synthetic
> sugar in mysql**."

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft SQL Server for instance, Schemas refer to a single user and is another level of a container in the order of indicating the server, database, schema, tables, and objects.

For example, when you are intending to update dbo.table_a and the syntax isn't full qualified such as 
UPDATE table.a the DBMS can't decide to use the intended table. Essentially by default the DBMS will utilize myuser.table_a

Comment: Schema's are *owned* by a single user.  By default, a user created in the database uses the dbo schema as their default schema.  The default schema used for a non fully qualified table reference is what is set for that user.

Comment: In older versions of SQL Server, deleting a user would render the schema that was associated with it unusable. These days the mapping between user and schema is less strict. Also, it is considered best practice to make a single fake account to owner of the database and all of the schemas.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some more info:

MongoDB also distinguish `schema` from `database`.

`schema` represent the tables, which means the structure of `database`.

Answer (score 0):

not like Postgres, SQL server schema is set of database have same thing
but in mysql schema and database it is the same
MySQL does not support the concept of schema. In MySQL, schema and schemas are synonyms for database and databases.

When a user connects to MySQL, they don't connect to a specific database. Instead, they can access any table they have permissions for

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the terms "schema" and "database" are often used interchangeably, but they have distinct meanings:

1. **Database:**

   - A database in MySQL is a container for a set of tables, views, stored procedures, and other database objects.
   - It is a physical or logical container for storing and organizing data.
   - In MySQL, you can create multiple databases on a server, and each database operates independently of others.

     ```sql
     CREATE DATABASE mydatabase;
     ```
2. **Schema:**

   - A schema, in MySQL, is a way to organize database objects within a database.
   - It is a collection of database objects, including tables, views, triggers, and other entities.
   - A database can have one or more schemas, and each schema can be used to group related objects together.

     ```sql
     CREATE SCHEMA myschema;
     ```
   - In practice, when you create a table in MySQL without explicitly specifying a schema, it is created in the default schema for the connected user. The terms "schema" and "database" are often used interchangeably, especially when referring to the structure of the database.

     ```sql
     CREATE TABLE myschema.mytable (
          column1 INT,
          column2 VARCHAR(50)
     );
     ```