# JDBC: Connection returning NULL, what to do?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, null, database-connection

This is the output of the program given below:

```
Connection made!
Schema Name:null

Successfully connected to null
Releasing all open resources ...
```

Inside establishConnection(), conn is initialized as null. Then the first statement inside the try block is supposed to establish a connection with the database, and the third statement is then printing the name of the current schema of conn.

According to the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), ***getSchema() returns the current schema name or null if there is none.***

**This means that there is no schema (I think the schema name is same as the database name) associated with conn? Can anyone suggest if I am correct in my anticipation, and also suggest why is that there is no schema or null associated with conn?**

```
public class ConnectDB {

    private Connection establishConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_final1", "root", "password");
            System.out.println("Connection made!");
            System.out.println("Schema Name:"+conn.getSchema()+"\n");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.err.println("SQL Exception thrown while making connection");
            printSQLException(sqle);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectDB cdb= new ConnectDB();
        Connection myconn=null;
        try{
            myconn=cdb.establishConnection();
            if(myconn!=null) System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + myconn.getSchema());
        }catch (SQLException e) {
              ConnectDB.printSQLException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        } finally {
          ConnectDB.closeConnection(myconn);
        }

    }
```

Comment: THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE. The other question is about Android, very much about the JTDs driver (I haven't used that). I am posting this comment for clarification, since I had got a comment saying that it is a duplicate, which was deleted after my explanation.

Comment: Where is the code where you have loaded the `MYSQL Driver`

Comment: People! The problem is not about getting a `null` connection but about a `null` return value from executing `Connection#getSchema` method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support the concept of *schema*. For MySQL, the schema is in fact the database. From [MySQL Glossary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_schema):

> **schema**
>
> Conceptually, a schema is a set of interrelated database objects, such as tables, table columns, data types of the columns, indexes, foreign keys, and so on. (...)

Based on [this answer from MySQL forums](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,518798,518816#msg-518816), you can't get the current database (or databases) through [`Connection#getSchema`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getSchema--) method (which was added since Java 7 with JDBC 4) but using [`Connection#getCatalog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getCatalog--) *unless you use the latest JDBC jar driver*:

> The JDBC driver (because of legacy, mysql didn't call them "schemas" until 5.0, and JDBC didn't have a way to select schemas until JDBC4), calls databases "catalogs", so thus you have to call getCatalogs() to get the list of databases

I made a dirty quick to prove the italic sentence above (*unless you use the latest JDBC jar driver*). Using `getCatalog()` worked using Java 6:

```
public class DirtyQuickTest {
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:7841/test";
    private static final String user = "lmendozaj";
    private static final String password = "s3cr3t"; //I won't show you my password
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            //commented since doesn't exists in Java 6
            //System.out.println(con.getSchema());
            System.out.println(con.getCatalog());
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test
```

Then I executed the same code in Java 8 and uncommented the statement containing `getSchema` using mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar (currently the latest Java Connector Driver for MySQL). This was the output:

```
null
test
```

Which means they still don't support `getSchema` method.

Related:

- [Difference Between Schema / Database in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618277/1065197)