# Search for the Date "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in entire MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a Huge database and somewhere in some table, there is a field with a **datetime** format that is corrupted with "0000-00-00 00:00:00" value.

How can I make a query, that will search for given datetime value ex. "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in entire database in all tables and all columns and rows?

Answer (score 2):

With *plain* mysql I think there is no way. So it depends on the programming language you have available. Ofc. every language is supporting native commands of mysql, which would allow you to write a script performing the required search:

First, you need to fetch all tables:

```
SHOW TABLES
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html

Then, in the first loop process every table, retrieving all the columns of the current table:

```
 SHOW COLUMNS FROM tableName WHERE TYPE =  'date' -- Maybe you use other types?
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

Finally, you could use the *outer* value *tableName* along with the *inner* value *columnName* to retrieve the result, you are seeking for:

```
SELECT * from tableName WHERE columnName = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

So, Script wise it might look like this (pseudocode):

```
$tables = query("SHOW TABLES");
foreach($tables as $tableName){
   $columns = query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableName WHERE TYPE =  'date'");
   foreach ($columns AS $columnName) {
      $res = query("SELECT * from $tableName WHERE $columnName = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';");

      foreach ($res AS $row){
         echo "Table $tableName has a invalid date in column $columnName for row {$row["id"]}";
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

SELECT TOP 1(*) FROM yourTable ORDER BY yourDateTimeColumn

The top 1 row should probably be the one with the value you're looking for

BTW, I thought SQL dates aren't earlier than 1900

Comment: I have a huge database, there are a lot of tables. Do not want to search for it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in one simple query, but you can make a query that will construct a complicated one for you; I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973732/mysql-searching-for-value-across-multiple-databases/31973962#31973962).
In your case, you will probably need to have a `DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'` condition in the where, instead of the linked example's column_name condition.

Comment: yes, in my DB there are two date formats used: datetime and timestamp

Comment: @It_Does_Not_Matter then it would be `IN ('datetime', 'timestamp')` instead