# Mysql Backup with create schema

Tags: mysql

I am in need of backing up a data base (dump) that come with create schema. What is the command line using putty (via SSH) to do this job ? I researched and thought this command but it does only the tables backup and data.

```
mysqldump -h HOST -u LOGIN -pSENHA --opt --routines --triggers BANCO > backup.sql
```

Comment: that'll dump everything necessary to recreate the `BANCO` database... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well, almost, @MarcB. It omits the `create database` statements. Try `mysqldump ... --databases BANCO` instead of only giving BANCO, i.e. `mysqldump -h HOST -u LOGIN -pSENHA --opt --routines --triggers --databases BANCO > backup.sql`

Comment: Need to beckup so that when running SQL generated he has the possibility of creating my schema, or may need to beckup with creat schema together with him.

Comment: `create db` isn't usually included in there. it's expected that a db will already exist when you load a dump into it.

Comment: However when I do the beckup by workbench he me the option to generate code with creat schema, like to do the same thing with the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases) `--databases BANCO`, i.e.

```
mysqldump -h HOST -u LOGIN -pSENHA --opt --routines --triggers --databases BANCO > backup.sql
```

This will add `create database` (and `drop database`) statements to the dump.

And in case you wonder: `schema` and `database` are synonymous in MySQL: [Difference Between Schema / Database in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11618277/5830574).

Comment: His command of error, because it is a line both repedindo, would have as review and edit the answer ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I  got you right, but you enter that in _one line_. Ok, I'll edit.