# Hibernate not specifying schema on generated HQL query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

So, I have a spring boot + hibernate application which has a main schema specified in the yml file (molecular) and also needs to fetch stuff from 3 others (vivax, malaria, chassis)

So, all schemas have access via the same user and are all accessible via port 3306, so my dev.yml file connection area looks like:

```
datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/molecular?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
        username: universalUser
        password: universalPass
```

I've set `EntityScan` like:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
    "org.wwarn.malaria.server.data",
    "org.wwarn.chassis.server.data",
    "org.wwarn.surveyorDM.domain.vivax",
    "org.wwarn.surveyorDM.domain"})
```

So it doesn't get scared when seeing 'alien' entities, so the app compiles and starts fine

However, when I try to do a default Repository operation on any of the packages (except `org.wwarn.surveyorDM.domain`) it won't build the HQL query properly, let's say I need to find all `vivax.Category`:

In the domain class I have specified the schema:

```
@Entity
  @Table(name = "Category", schema = "vivax")
```

It has its jpa repository:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category,Long> {

}
```

But the hql query will come out as:

```
Hibernate: select category0_.id as id1_59_, category0_.name as name2_59_, category0_.version as version3_59_ from Category category0_
```

When I need it to specify `vivax.Category` in the `FROM` clause

So, if I add the following native query to the repository:

```
@Query(value="select distinct * from vivax.Category", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Category> findAllCats();
```

It works like a charm

Any ideas out there as to how to force hibernate to add schema in `FROM` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try specifying the schema like below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vivax.Category")
```

Comment: Why is it the trick is always so blatantly simple?! Makes one feel so stupid at times :) Thanks for that it worked like a charm

Comment: This does not work with `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers` on

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you are using a MYSQL database,[and in mysql there is no difference between schema and database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618277/difference-between-schema-database-in-mysql). I suspect that is the reason that the schema property gets ignored when you are connecting to a MYSQL database. For example, this works fine on a POSTGRESQL database. I would try with the approach proposed by juserman10, and that is putting the db and the table name concatenated in the `@Table` annotation name property.

If that doesn't work, you can configure multiple data sources in your application, one for each database.