# Hibernate choose database name for entities

Tags: hibernate

As you must be aware in `MySQL` namespaces and database are essentially the same thing.

How can I tell hibernate to use a particular `db` for an `Entity`. It by default uses the one defined in the `spring.datasource.url`. So here it would be looking entities in `db1` database.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1
```

If I use 
`@Table(name= db2.sample_table)` it looks for `db1.db2_sample_table`

Comment: The `@Table` annotation has a `schema` property. `@Table(name = "sample_table", schema="db2")` should be sufficient.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, it's ignoring the schema and looking in default schema only.

Comment: As your question has been viewed 11 times now it might have been anyone else who voted on your question. I don't see a reason to close this. BTW: You may accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there seems to be a [bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10408) in `Hibernate` 5.0+ and `MySql` and using schema syntax doesn't work because `MySql` [considers both schema and database same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618277/difference-between-schema-database-in-mysql)

```
@Table(name="some_table", schema="db2")
```

instead one can use `catalog` instead of `schema`.

```
@Table(name="some_table", catalog="db2")
```