# What is the Postgresql SQL query analogous to 'USE database_name' from MySQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to execute a script from Java code which should create a database and then a table in that database. How do I do it in PostgreSQL?

1. `CREATE DATABASE mydb`
2. `USE mydb` // doesn't work for PostgreSQL
3. `CREATE TABLE mytable (.....)`

What SQL do we give for Step 2 in PosgreSQL?

Version : 9.5

Comment: psql is more about commands and not SQL, I guess ?

Answer (score 0):

Almost this question has been asked before ([Difference Between Schema / Database in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618277/difference-between-schema-database-in-mysql))

This has a reference to chapter 5.8 'Schemas': https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html

If your answer was 'how are schemas implemented under PostgreSQL', than this might be the correct answer. I think you cannot use `use ..`, and you have to use `mydb.mytable`. (or set a search pattern `SET search_path TO mydb,public;`)

Comment: Your first link is about the difference between schema and database in MySQL, it is not 'almost this question'.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: The question how to use a schema, and  raghav know how to do it in MySQL. For the answer of this question it might be smart to know the differences, which is explained in this first link.