# What is the difference between a database and a schema?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I've tried to find the distinction between the terms database and a database schema. I've seen some answers in Stack Overflow itself but they were not sufficient to get a good idea of the differences between the two. Can someone please explain this comprehensively with details.

Also, I've read that DDL is used on schema and not on the database. What does this mean?

Is it true if I call a schema being a sub-set of a database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference Between Schema / Database in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618277/difference-between-schema-database-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks. But the answer provided here says that in MySQL both are synonymous. Suppose this is a question asked in an exam paper, what must my answer be?

Comment: Also, I've read that DDL is used on schema and not on the database. What does this mean?

Comment: Is it true if I call a schema being a sub-set of a database?

Comment: Not in mysql's case and you should read up on DDL (data definition language) and DML (data manipulation language)